# How to make a php array of a mysql_fetch_array while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, while-loop

At the moment I have a large number of php files, each one with an array statement in the format:

```
$array1 = array ( array ( 'Husband' => 'bob',
                          'Wife' => 'ann' ),
                  array ( 'Husband' => 'fred',
                          'Wife' => 'donna' ),
                  array ( 'Husband' => 'john',
                          'Wife' => 'mary' ) );
```

This of course returns from `print_r ($array1)` the output (A):

```
    Array ( [0] => Array (
                  [Husband] => bob [Wife] => ann ) 
           [1] => Array ( 
                  [Husband] => fred [Wife] => donna ) 
           [2] => Array ( [Husband] => john [Wife] => mary ) )
```

In a separate class file, I access $array1 data, using statements like:

```
for ($col = 0; $col < sizeof($array1); $col++)
{
  echo $array[$col]['Wife']."<br />";
}
```

On the theory that a large number of anything is a database, I am wanting to migrate the data in the multiple php array files array into a MySQL database, and access the MySQL data from my class file.  So I set up the following in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `arrays` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `husband` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `wife` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `arrays` (`id`, `husband`, `wife`) VALUES
(1, 'bob', 'ann'),
(2, 'fred', 'donna'),
(3, 'john', 'mary');
```

Then I access this MySQL database from PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`arrays`";
$link  = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'username', 'password' ) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ('database', $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $array2 = array ( 'Husband' => $row['husband'],
                    'Wife' => $row['wife'] );
  print_r ($array2);
}
```

This will produce output (B) like:

```
Array ( [Husband] => bob [Wife] => ann ) 
Array ( [Husband] => fred [Wife] => donna ) 
Array ( [Husband] => john [Wife] => mary )
```

My question is how do I make a php array of the mysql_fetch_array while loop, so that output B looks like output A.  I want to be able to continue to access the data in my class file in the manner `$array[$col]['Wife']`, but from the MySQL database.

Comment: Please dont call your table 'arrays thats bad practice. It should be more descriptive of the objects you are storing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do here is push the array returned by `mysql_fetch_array()` onto a larger array using `[]`:

```
$MultiDimArray = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $MultiDimArray[] = array ( 'Husband' => $row['husband'], 'Wife' => $row['wife'] );
}

print_r($MultiDimArray);
```

Now, a few comments:

- *Please* don't write new code with the `mysql_*` extension, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.
- Use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)  instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` unless you explicitly want numerically indexed keys as well as associative.
- If you name your columns (including capitalisation) the same way as you use the keys in your code, you can simply push the return value of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` onto the array.

For example:

```
while ($MultiDimArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) continue;
```

- Don't use `or die(mysql_error());` constructs. You should *never* show the result of `mysql_error()` (or it's PDO/MySQLi equivalent) in a production environment, and if you must do it for debugging make sure you remove it from your code immediately afterwards.
- Don't use `sizeof($array1)` directly as a loop condition. It is very inefficient, the only time you should ever do it is if the size of your array may change during the loop. You should call `sizeof()` once before the loop, store the result in a variable, and compare `$col` against that variable.

For example:

```
for ($col = 0, $size = sizeof($array1); $col < $size; $col++)
{
  echo $array1[$col]['Wife']."<br />";
}

// Also, don't forget you could simply do this:
foreach ($array1 as $row)
{
  echo $row['Wife']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for both your solution, and your insightful suggestions.  I am a better programmer for all of it!

Answer (score 1):

try to change your code this way

```
$array2 = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`arrays`";
$link  = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'username', 'password' ) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ('database', $link) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $array2[] = array ( 'Husband' => $row['husband'],
                    'Wife' => $row['wife'] );
}

print_r ($array2);
```

I believe that is the result you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $temparray = array ( 'Husband' => $row['husband'],
                    'Wife' => $row['wife'] );
  array_push($array2, $temparray);
}

print_r ($array2);
```

Comment: I guess $array2[] is better if you're only adding one variable at a time.